# C# Nested EF Seed method got me cornered

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've made a 1000 line seed code which will not work because of the structure.

I have the following **entities**:

**Program** : is a workout program that contains Workouts.

**Workout** : is a day routine that contains a list of Sets.

**Set**     : is an Exercises repeated x times with y load.

**Exercise**: is an gym exercise which contains a Region.

**Region**  : is a region on the human body and contains Muscles.

**Muscle**  : is a muscle on the human body.

## Model examples

Here are 3 model examples, and its between those 3, the binding goes wrong i think.

```
    public class Workout
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkoutId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Set> Sets { get; set; }
}
 public class Set
{
    [Key]
    public int SetId { get; set; }
    //Foreign key for Exercise
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ExerciseId")]
    public Exercise Exercise { get; set; }
    public decimal Load { get; set; }
    public decimal Order { get; set; }
}

    public class Exercise
{
    [Key]
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //Foreign key for Region
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

## Seed method

I've made a long seed method filling in an example program, all the regions and relevant muscles.

The way i seeded the **Regions** and **Mucles** - which works fine

```
Regions = new List<Region>
        {
            new Region
            {
                RegionName = "Neck",
                Muscles = new List<Muscle>
                {
                    new Muscle {LatinName = "Omohyoid", DkName = "", EnName = "", Description = ""},
                    new Muscle {LatinName = "Sternohyoid", DkName = "", EnName = "", Description = ""},
//etc etc etc...
```

The way i seed **Exercises** - which works fine

```
 Exercises = new List<Exercise>
        {
            new Exercise
            {
                Name = "Benchpress",
                Description = "Flat barbel",
                Region = Regions.Find(x => x.RegionName == "Chest"),
```

But then i want to create alot of **Set**s, the actual Program.

```
Sets = new List<Set>
        {
            //single Set
            new Set
            {
                Exercise = Exercises.Find(x => x.Name == "Bænkpres"),
                Load = 0.0M,
                Order = 1.0M,

      //etc etc..
```

then i create a **Workout**:

```
 Workouts = new List<Workout>
                {   //single Workout

                    new Workout
                    {
                        Name = "Chest", Description = "",
                        //Set list
                        Sets = Sets
```

I have tried alot of things, ending out in following error:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: Unable to determine
the principal end of the 'Gym.Models.Set_Exercise' relationship. 
Multiple added entities may have the same primary key. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: 
Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Gym.Models.Set_Exercise'
relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.
```

Im not really sure where to go from now, i would really appreciate for this to work without re-writing my many many **Set**s.

So someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried adding `virtual` to the `Exercise` property in `Set`?

Comment: You rock! I deleted the ExerciseId and the ForeignKey annotation. Then i made the Exercise virtual and it all worked, Tanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.